# All do blocks in mapM are executed before main computation inside do block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

In the following, when `mapM` executes in `decryptParallel`, the `tick pg` call in `decryptProgress`'s `do` block immediately completes for all items in the list `encrBytes`, instantly completing the progress bar. After this, the program then waits while all of the `decrypt key encrBytes` take place, rendering the progress bar useless.

What's going on here?

I also tried converting the Lazy ByteString to a strict version with `B.toStrict` before `tick pg`, and that did not help either.

```hs
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import System.Console.AsciiProgress (Options(..), displayConsoleRegions,
                                        isComplete, def, newProgressBar, tick, ProgressBar, complete)

decryptProgress :: ProgressBar -> B.ByteString -> B.ByteString -> IO B.ByteString
decryptProgress pg key encrBytes = do
    let decrBytes = decrypt key encrBytes
    tick pg
    return decrBytes

decryptParallel :: B.ByteString -> [B.ByteString] -> IO [B.ByteString]
decryptParallel key encrBytes = displayConsoleRegions $ do
    pg <- newProgressBar def {pgTotal = (toInteger $ length encrBytes)}
    decrBytes <- mapM (decryptProgress pg key) encrBytes
    return decrBytes

main = do
    encrBytes <- ...
    key <- ...
    decrBytes <- decryptParallel key encrBytes
    B.writeFile "temp" decrBytes
```

Comment: You're still being bit by laziness. `decryptProgress` doesn't return the decrypted bytestring, it returns a thunk. Force the bytestring to weak head normal form using `$!` or `seq` before calling tick and you should be good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is lazy evaluation. The value `decrBytes` is not required within `decryptProgress`, so it isn't "forced" (i.e. actually evaluated). Internally it is represented as a "thunk"; a data structure containing a function pointer and the necessary arguments. If at some point in the future the value is actually needed then the function will be executed and the thunk replaced with the actual value.

Meanwhile your progress bar is updated promptly by the `tick :: ProgressBar -> IO ()` function.

One way around this would be to force the value of `decrBytes` using [`seq`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq). I haven't tried it, but you should be able to do this with

> seq decrBytes $ return decrBytes

Also try putting some [`trace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) calls in your code. One in `decrypt` should help you see what is going on.

**Edit:**

As @melpomene points out in the comments, there is also [`evaluate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate) in `Control.Exception`. This will do basically the same as the `seq` call I gave above, but will also do it in the `IO` monad. Hence you could replace your `let` with

> decrBytes <- evaluate $ decrypt key encrBytes

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate

Comment: Thank you @Paul Johnson and @melpomene!